# AspNet core 2.1 SignalR Angular 7

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, angular7

I want to add a comment to a specific user and, if that user at the moment online,then that user to show a notification regarding to that comment.
And later I want to add messaging system too.

I followed many articles, they are using **@aspnet/signalr-client** package in angular app.But I can't install it and occurs this error

```
This package has been deprecated. Use '@aspnet/signalr' instead.
```

I wasted much time for this problem.
Can you please give me an article or any other code related to this problem.
What I want to know is,

How to connect user with server and connected users between communication.then

1. When user log into system after that user's friends to indicate
   current user in their friends list.
2. If that user logout / disconnect then also that users friends to
   indicate it.
3. **If a specific user to add comment then that user online at that
   moment,that user to see is it as a notification**

3rd one is very important.If someone can give a piece of code for this,very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@aspnet/signalr` package which is stated in [GitHub Repository of AspNetCore](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/SignalR/README.md)

[Here is](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/SignalR/samples) Samples which you can take a look.

For basic tutorial (simply how to start): [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks alot Simonare,I followed these samples earlier.These samples doesn't contain web client parts and the basic tutorial does not contains some parts.Actually I'm a beginner to SignalR.This is my first time using this.However I think something can do using your basic tutorial.I'll give you an update.thanks again :)

Comment: I tried this,now problem is,I want to send a message a particular user.
I tried to get user name using Context.User.Identity.Name inside OnConnectedAsync method.but I couldn't get username,it shown as null value

Comment: check [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I want to do connection establishment when login,now it's doing separately.first login to system with another service and return token,after that  SignalR will connect.

Comment: I opened another question too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975313/how-to-make-signalr-connection-establishment-when-login-in-asp-net-core-2-1-an